# Mat-form-field - Styling when out of focus and with text in mat-input

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

How can I make it so that the out of focus styles don't apply when there is text inside the mat-input while simultaneously being out of focus?

I want to keep these styles when out of focus and with text:

[image]

But right now this is what I'm getting when out of focus and with text:

[image]

Also, this is how the field looks when there is no text and out of focus:

[image]

My current styles:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    background-color: #FFFFFF66;
    border-radius: 10em;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in the comments that you have noticed Angular removes the `mat-focused` class, so applying it to the `mat-form-field` directly will not work. However, we should be able to apply classes to a wrapper container that will match the 'focused' style.

- `div.mat-form-field-outline` has 'focused' rules when nested in an
  element with `mat-form-field-appearance-outline` and `mat-focused`
  classes
- The `mat-label` element has 'focused' rules when nested in an element
  with `mat-form-field` and `mat-focused` classes.

So we can provide the `mat-form-field-appearance-outline` and `mat-form-field` classes to a container and toggle the `mat-focused` class based on the form field value.

```
<p>
  <span
    class="mat-form-field mat-form-field-appearance-outline"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-focused': field.value}"
  >
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
      <input #field matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
      <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
  </span>
</p>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckvs4z?file=src/app/form-field-appearance-example.html

Comment: You sir just made my day! I cannot thank you enough. I really appreciate you taking the time to help a noob junior dev like myself :-)

Comment: No problem at all, looks like you are up to some cool stuff, I wish you good luck

Comment: Oh and by the way, I forgot to ask: would it also be possible if I wanted to keep the focused style like the way it is in your answer, but with a different border opacity? If so, how? I was thinking of doing 0.5 opacity for the border when out of focus + with text.

Comment: Should be able to do it with something like: .mat-focused mat-form-field:not(.mat-focused)  -  I updated the stackblitz if you want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost exactly that! But what I was looking for was something like: border 0.5 opacity, but the floating label and the text inside the input field remain with opacity 1.

Comment: Ah, ok. You should be able to target that with .mat-form-field-outline-thick

Comment: Right on the money again! However, I never messed around with SASS, do I just need to rename the global styles.css to styles.scss? Or is there a way to have it on my component folder somehow?

Comment: You should be able to rename it, assuming your project is setup to support sass. I'd recommend using it as it makes a lot of tedious css stuff a lot more simple. For this specific case you can just use normal css nesting as well though.

Comment: Nested CSS did the trick :-) I will definitely check out SASS in the future. Appreciate it, you saved me again today.